# Django - variables in django templates

Tags: django

Is it possible to write something like this in django templates:

```
{% for subcategory in category.subcategory.all %}
        <li style="padding-left:20px">
          <a href="/{{category.slug}}/{{subcategory.slug}}">
         {{ subcategory.name }}
         {{ sub_ + str(subcategory) }}
   </a></li>  
{% endfor %} <br>
```

In my views.py I have:

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    categories = Category.objects.select_related()
    subcategories = SubCategory.objects.all()
    context['categories'] = categories
    context['subcategories'] = subcategories
    for subcategory in subcategories:
        sites = Site.objects.filter(subcategory=subcategory, is_active=True)
        print(sites.count())
        context['sub_' + str(subcategory)] = sites.count()
        print(context)
    return render(request, 'mainapp/index.html', context)
```

I need to count Sites in each subcategory. I thought I can do it by making sub_category1, sub_category2 variables. But I don't know how can I get it in my template. Any ideas? When I write {{ sub_category1 }} it works. I need to put

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{{ sub_ + str(subcategory) }}
```

No, this isn't going to work.

I would create a method on the `SubCategory` model:

```
def get_active_sites(self):
    return Site.objects.filter(subcategory=self, is_active=True)
```

Now you can use

```
{{ subcategory.get_active_sites.count }}
```

in the template. Similarly I'd replace `/{{category.slug}}/{{subcategory.slug}}` with a method on SubCategory that uses `reverse()`; probably named `get_absolute_url()`.

Comment: I tried your solution but I got "Cannot resolve keyword 'active' into field. Choices are: category, category_id, date, description, id, is_active, keywords, name, subcategory, subcategory_id, url
"

Comment: So I made a typing mistake, but it should be obvious from the error message and your knowledge of your own models...

Comment: Oh yes... Of course. My fault...;) Thank you. It works fine.